# Selenium after take screenshot unlink txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have some txt files in a folder, I have listed directory and garbed links. After visit links using selenium I have taken screenshot. Now I am trying do delete this link txt file.

Below code I have tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

path = "E:/xampp/htdocs/spool/"
directories = os.listdir(path)
for dir in directories:
    # print(dir)
    files = os.listdir(path+dir)
    for file in files:
        # print(path+dir+'/'+file)
        f = open(path+dir+'/'+file, "r")
        list = f.read()
        data = list.split("||")
        print(data[1])
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get(data[1])
        driver.save_screenshot(data[0]+'.png')
        driver.close()
        os.unlink(f.name)
```

Problem is unlink time it's giving below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 21, in <module>
    os.unlink(f.name)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'E:/xampp/htdocs/spool/7/2020-09-1112.txt'
```

I have also used `os.close(3)`, After that got error "

```
list = f.read()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

"
How can I unlink after take screenshot ?

```
Version python : Python 3.8.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As u can see another process is using the txt file.

I think that's the problem here; you opened the file and didn't closed it.

I suggets you to visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm

Try to call `f.close()` and then unlink.

Answer (score 1):

This method of **file handling** is not entirely safe.
If an exception occurs when we are performing some operation with the file, the code exits with out closing the file.

In your case you forgot to close the file.

```
f.close()
```

I would recommend to use this approach to avoid such scenarios

```
with open("test.txt", mode= 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    # perform file operations
    pass
    # we dont need to explicitly close() the method, it is done internally.
```